# Large values while calculating on normalized difference indexes

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, ndvi, normalized-difference-water-index

I've encountered a problem while calculating NDDI index (NDVI-NDWI/NDVI+NDWI) in ArcGIS Pro for my bachelor's thesis. I'm working with Raster Calculator (the problem appeared in both Image Analyst Tools and Spatial Analyst Tools Raster Calculator) and using two different raster layers (NDVI and NDWI). Both of those layers are in 32bit float format and have values spanning from -1 to 1 as it should be. The output raster has absurdly large values (-413443 to 3829913).

What can it be caused by and how can I fix it?

I suspect it may be due to float format.

[image]

[image]